# Проблема со сравнением строки

Tags: c

есть такое задание, необходимо Вывести названия книг определенного автора, изданных после 2000 года и определить долю книг в библиотеке по теме «Программирование» от общего количества экземпляров. НО я не знаю как вывести книги определенного автора (потому что я не умею сравнивать наверное указатель на символы и символы) и по той же причине не могу вывести книги по теме программирование. Вот моя реализация:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Books
{
    char surname[100];
    char title[100];
    char publisher[100];
    int year;
    char theme[100];
};
char vvod;
int save(char* filename, struct Books* st, int n);
int load(char* filename);

int main(void)
{
    char* filename = "d.dat";
    struct Books parametrs[] = {
    "Толстой", "Война и мир", "ОАО Книжный", 2001, "Художественная литература",
    "Достоевский", "Преступление и наказание", "Мир книги", 1900, "Художественная литература",
    "Петров", "Программирование в С", "КнигаЛенд", 2002, "Программирование"};
    int n = sizeof(parametrs) / sizeof(parametrs[0]);
    save(filename, parametrs, n);
    load(filename);
    return 0;
}
int save(char* filename, struct Books* st, int n)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char* c;
    int size = n * sizeof(struct Books);
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Файл не открыт");
        return 1;
    }
    c = (char*)&n;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        putc(*c++, fp);
    }
    c = (char*)st;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        putc(*c, fp);
        c++;
    }
    fclose(fp); 
    return 0;
}
int load(char* filename)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char* c;
    int m = sizeof(int);
    int n, i;
    int* pti = (int*)malloc(m);
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Невозможно открыть файл");
        return 1;
    }
    c = (char*)pti;
    while (m > 0)
    {
        i = getc(fp);
        if (i == EOF) break;
        *c = i;
        c++;
        m--;
    }
    n = *pti; 
    struct Books* ptr = (struct Books*)malloc(n * sizeof(struct Books));
    c = (char*)ptr;
    while ((i = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        *c = i;
        c++;
    }
    char a1[100]  = "Достоевский";
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        if ((ptr + k)->year>2000){
            printf("%d %s %s %s %d %s\n", k + 1, (ptr + k)->surname, (ptr + k)->title, (ptr + k)->publisher, (ptr + k)->year, (ptr + k)->theme);
       }
    }
    free(pti);
    free(ptr);
    fclose(fp); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: strcmp в помощь, наверное?